# Enforcing method calls

Tags: ruby, dsl

I am playing around with creating a DSL. I am using http://jroller.com/rolsen/entry/building_a_dsl_in_ruby as a guide.

Given this DSL:

```
question 'Who was the first president of the USA?'
wrong 'Fred Flintstone'
wrong 'Martha Washington'
right 'George Washington'
wrong 'George Jetson'
```

is there a way to make sure that question() is called at least once, right() exactly once and wrong() n or more times?

Comment: Ugh, I’d really put the answers inside the `do` block of the `question`.

Comment: Agreed. And in which case, set the right answer as a single value, while wrong adds to an array.

Comment: What does it mean to "make sure" that these are called? Do you want it to raise an error if they're not?

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Let's say that it took options. Something like like: options {:num_questions=>6 ...}. How would you make sure that options is called? Amazing how a simple question results in off-topic banter.

Comment: @jleevdev, bring that up to Russ Olsen not me.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just add the line

```
(@question_count ||= 0) += 1
```

to whatever your current implementation of the `question` method looks like (and similarly for `right` and `wrong`) and then check those variables.

Answer (score 0):

The handling of answering is missing in the following code, but you have control of only one right answer

```
class Question
  def initialize(text)
    @text = text
    @answers = []
    @correct = nil #index of the correct answer inside @answers
  end
  def self.define(text, &block)
    raise ArgumentError, "Block missing" unless block_given?
    q = self.new(text)
    q.instance_eval(&block)    
    q
  end
  def wrong( answer )
    @answers << answer
  end
  def right(answer )
    raise "Two right answers" if @correct
    @answers << answer
    @correct = @answers.size
  end
  def ask()
    puts @text
    @answers.each_with_index{|answer, i|
      puts "\t%2i %s?" % [i+1,answer]
    }
    puts "correct is %i" % @correct
  end
end

def question( text, &block )
  raise ArgumentError, "Block missing" unless block_given?
  Question.define(text, &block)
end
```

Now you can define your question with block syntax:

```
question( 'Who was the first president of the USA?' ) {
  wrong 'Fred Flintstone'
  wrong 'Martha Washington'
  right 'George Washington'
  wrong 'George Jetson'
}.ask
```

You may use also another definition of questions:

```
q = Question.new( 'Who was the first president of the USA?' )
q.wrong 'Fred Flintstone'
q.wrong 'Martha Washington'
q.right 'George Washington'
q.wrong 'George Jetson'
q.ask
```